# Ormlite 4.9 changed on create tables and create or update functions

Tags: java, orm, ormlite

After I upgraded my version from 4.4 to 4.9, I found that ORMLite has deprecate some of the method on:

1. TableUtils, which is: createTableIfNotExists
2. Dao, which is: createOrUpdate

Meanwhile, my sistem which I built using ORMLite are many already. Can anybody advice me on how the latest ORMLite handles both cases? I cannot seems to find any documentation on how 2 functions can be use in the 4.9 version.

Or should I replace ORMLite completely and goes back to more stable orm libs (such Hibernate -> which forced me to use many jars if I wanna use it).

Thanks

Comment: Yes ... after I read carefully on download page ... I realized that 4.9 was committed on 2010, while 4.47 was on this year :) ... so I put back to 4.47 .... sight mistakes LOL

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> After I upgraded my version from 4.4 to 4.9, I found that ORMLite has deprecate some of the method on:

The latest ORMLite release is 4.47. You sure you didn't move from 4.4X to 4.9 which is a downgrade?  See the [ChangeLog for details of what changed](http://ormlite.com/changelog.txt) in what release.

Unfortunately, the sorting down via the maven web server is done in alphabetic order which orders 4.9 *after* 4.47.

Comment: Come on! Can't believe my eyes.